# retrieve picture taken from the application

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

is ti possibile to save a picture (taken with UIImagePickerController) in the camera roll, either using

```
writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock
```

or

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(..)
```

that allow me to know, iterating the the camera roll using ALAssetsLibrary, in a second moment if the picture was taken by the application? is there a way so to store a flag "taken in-app" for a picture without making me save the list of url?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add this information to metadata, possibly as a `userComment` or `make:model:software:`

There's a nice tutorial on this subject here: [Adding metadata to iOS images the easy way](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/)

And for reading metadata: [Getting metadata from images on iOS](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios)